# Extracting Values from rdflib.term.URIRef and rdflib.term.Literal

Tags: sparql, rdflib

I am newbie to SPARQL queries and I am getting error when trying to extract the values from `rdflib.term.URIRef` and `rdflib.term.Literal`. So `?o` contains both URI and Literals. Please find the below query.

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  uo:0A ?p ?o.
  BIND(IF(!isLITERAL(?o), (strafter(str(?o), '#') as ?o2), ?o) AS ?result)
}
```

I am getting error as `ParseException: Expected {SelectQuery | ConstructQuery | DescribeQuery | AskQuery}, found 'B'  (at char 117), (line:4, col:1)`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your `BIND` clause is broken, please check again the syntax of `IF`, currently you have `as` twice which obviously makes no sense as there is no `as` in any `IF` but only in the `BIND`

Comment: I actually used 'as' here for strafter and not for 'if' condition

Comment: Thank you, I am able to get the output now

Comment: right, `strafter` or `if` - doesn't matter. `AS` is only usable for `BIND`(or in projection part of the query) to assign a value to a variable. Please provide your solution as an answer and also accept it to mark the question as resolved. Thank you

Comment: @meghana-kb, could you please close this issue if it's solved? This allows us to manage StackOverflow questions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Re-posting comment content as an answer so this can be accepted and the question closed:*

Your BIND clause is broken, please check again the syntax of IF, currently you have as twice which obviously makes no sense as there is no as in any IF but only in the BIND.

AS is only usable for BIND(or in projection part of the query) to assign a value to a variable.